# How Add a Class after using the Method RemoveClass in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I wanna remove the class removetest "removetest" and replace it with "test".

I tried but I have not succeded. What am I missing?

Thanks!

```js
$('.chatinput').keyup(function(event) {
  newText = event.target.value;
  $('.printchatbox').text(newText);

  if (newText.length !== 0) {

    if ($(".remove").find(".removetest").length > 0) {
      alert('test');


      $(".remove").find(".removetest").removeClass('.removetest').

      $('asdf').addClass('.test');

      if ($(".remove").find(".test").length > 0) {
        alert('test2');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.printchatbox {
  border-width: thick 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #fff;
  line-height: 2;
  color: #6E6A6B;
  font-size: 14pt;
  text-align: left;
  float: middle;
  border: 3px solid #969293;
  width: 40%;
}
.test {
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.removetest {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class='printchatbox'>CHANGE ME</div>
  <input type='text' name='fname' class='chatinput'>


  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <div class='remove'>

    <div class='asdf removetest'>test</div>

  </div>

  <footer>
    <pre>Stack Overflow: Input text printed in box</pre>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: share your code in question

Comment: `$('.asdf').addClass('test');` missing `.` in `$('asdf')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need to precede `.` when you're adding or removing class using `addClass/removeClass`.

```js
$('.chatinput').keyup(function(event) {
  var newText = $.trim($(this).val());
  $('.printchatbox').text(newText);

  if (newText.length !== 0) {
    $('.remove .removetest').removeClass('removetest').addClass('test');
  }
});
```

```css
.printchatbox {
  border-width: thick 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #fff;
  line-height: 2;
  color: #6E6A6B;
  font-size: 14pt;
  text-align: left;
  float: middle;
  border: 3px solid #969293;
  width: 40%;
}
.test {
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.removetest {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='printchatbox'>CHANGE ME</div>
<input type='text' name='fname' class='chatinput'>
<br/>

<div class='remove'>
  <div class='asdf removetest'>test</div>
</div>

<footer>
  <pre>Stack Overflow: Input text printed in box</pre>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in the comments above there are few issues in how you are adding/removing the classes.

But since you might need to add/remove the `removetest`/`test` classes based on whether there is content in the text box, it will be easier to use `toggleClass()`

```js
$('.chatinput').keyup(function(event) {
  var newText = this.value;
  $('.printchatbox').text(newText);

  $(".remove .inner").toggleClass('removetest', newText.length == 0).toggleClass('test', newText.length > 0);
});
```

```css
 .printchatbox {
   border-width: thick 10px;
   border-style: solid;
   background-color: #fff;
   line-height: 2;
   color: #6E6A6B;
   font-size: 14pt;
   text-align: left;
   float: middle;
   border: 3px solid #969293;
   width: 40%;
 }
 .test {
   visibility: visible;
   background-color: yellow;
 }
 .removetest {
   visibility: hidden;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='printchatbox'>CHANGE ME</div>
<input type='text' name='fname' class='chatinput' />
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class='remove'>
  <div class='inner removetest'>test</div>
</div>
<footer>
  <pre>Stack Overflow: Input text printed in box</pre>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

First u set id to div tag of "remove" class, then add the following code,
eg:

```
<div class='remove' id="id">

<script>
   $('#id').removeClass('removetest').addClass('test'); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("before removing:" + $("div>div").attr("class"));
  $(".remove").find(".removetest").removeClass('.asdf removetest');
  $("div>div").addClass("test");

  alert("after removing:" + $("div>div").attr("class"));


});
```

```css
.printchatbox {
  border-width: thick 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #fff;
  line-height: 2;
  color: #6E6A6B;
  font-size: 14pt;
  text-align: left;
  float: middle;
  border: 3px solid #969293;
  width: 40%;
}
.test {
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.removetest {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class='printchatbox'>CHANGE ME</div>
  <input type='text' name='fname' class='chatinput'>


  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <div id="t1" class='remove'>

    <div class='asdf removetest'>test</div>

  </div>

  <footer>
    <pre>Stack Overflow: Input text printed in box</pre>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```